# press button to make $("body").css("height":"100%")

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I want to use this functionality in my website (when press in 'SHOW IT') --> http://labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js/

The problem is that this functionality need to put body height to 100%. In some time, in me site I need to detect the scroll user to make topbar appear and disappear em some positions.

So to can join this two functionality's, I only change body height to 100% when I press button to show the div avground. But where I have a problem: the button is on page footer  and when I change body height, they automatically send me to the top of page and after show de div avground.

Is any way to this don't happen or is possible to scroll to footer before the div avground appear?

If someone have another solution, I appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: it's very hard to understand your language.. to make it easier please show all the relevant code..

Comment: the code envolve html, css and jquery. I just want to put this working --> labs.voronianski.com/jquery.avgrund.js but the button "SHOW IT" is in footer of me page and in some time I can't have my body with height 100%...I just do that when press button to show this functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using bootstrap's modals? They are very simple to make and look nicer in my opinion.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually have to do that, for that animation you can use simple CSS3:

CSS:

```
#layer-body {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#layer-body.hide {
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
    -moz-transform: scale(0.8);
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
#menu {
    background: rgba(208, 31, 60, .95);
    position: fixed; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 4;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
#menu.show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    transform: translateY(0%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}
#menu.hide {
    visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
    transition: transform 0.5s, visibility 0s 0.5s;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="layer-body"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
</body>
```

This means, all of your website will be inside #layer-body, and the menu inside #menu.

So when you open the menu you'll have to add the class HIDE to the #layer-body and SHOW to the #menu.